# Azure Role Instances Remote Desktop Asking for Different Certificate

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, certificate

I was following this Youtube guide on how to do remote desktop with Windows Azure Roles.
I followed the tutorial. 
In my Solution Explorer (in Visual Studio 2013), I right clicked on my project and hit package. In there, I clicked settings and created a new Certificate/created a .pfx file just like in the tutorial. I also uploaded the certificate in management portal Certificates. Then I tried to update my project in Azure, with that specific certificate, thenn it errored: The certificate with thumbprint yyyyy...yyyy was not found. However, the certificate that I used in the package has a different thumbprint, like xxxxx....xxxx. Nonetheless, this yyyy...yyyy thumbprint that was in the error message is in the dropdown list of the certificates that I can choose for the package, but that's not the one I choose.

I also tried to update my project first before installing this xxxxx....xxxxx thumbprint certificate. Then it would complain certificate with thumbprint with xxxxx.....xxxxx was not found. Then after installing this xxxxx.....xxxxx certificate, tried to update the package again, it would then complain about the yyyyy.....yyyyy thumbprint not found.

Any suggestions on what to try? Or any simple tutorial?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignore the Youtube guide :).  The new way to enable RDP is to deploy the package to Azure without RDP and then in the portal you can configure RDP.  This will dynamically inject the RDP agent into the VMs and it automatically handles all of the certificate issues for you.

Comment: Thank you! That worked for me.
Do you happen to know if the upload certificate from the portal is broken? I uploaded a certificate which expires in 2040 and it is really responsible for giving me access to some actual resource. It does not seem to take effect until I use the same certificate for remote access as you mentioned. (Furthermore, the certificate that I uploaded for the purpose of RDP did not show up in MMC in RDP... When I tried to RDP with this certificate, it would always complain the account has expired) Thank you very much!

Comment: I realized that the reason why the certificate that I tried to use for RDP (created by VS based on the video) wasn't installed, it's because the expiration is set to today. :)